# How do I recreate my free/busy information store in Exchange 2003?

Tags: windows, exchange

At one point tried to migrate exchange off of the domain controller, but I had some issues, so I migrated everything back. The only thing that didn't apparently migrate back was my free/busy, and its too late to pull it from the old server, as I have since decommissioned it. How would I go about recreating the store? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Please see this KB article:

[Free/Busy system folder is missing](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/284200)

It should walk you through the steps.  HOWEVER, I strongly caution you to know what you are doing and that if at all possible you contact MS support FIRST to have them assist.  Messing with ADSI edit with Exchange without knowing your environment and the "why" behind this can cause further issues.  Make sure you have good backups as well.